# What is the method of querying from two tables with a condition in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an invoice table and a detail table in the database and they have a relationship
What is the best way to query from two tables?
Provided that the invoice is of type 1 or 2

this code

```
    $Details = Invoice_Details::with(['invoice' => function($q){
        $q -> where('Invoice_type', 1);
    }]) -> with('invoice') -> get();

    return $Details -> sum('quantity');
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that invoice type is dynamically send by request on this situation
you can use query builder for that. in your case i think it may suit for you

```
 $query = Invoice_Details::query()-> with('invoice');
          
        
         if($request->invoice_type==1){

              $query->whereRelation('invoice','Invoice_type','=' ,1);
           }

    $Details = $query->get();

    return $Details -> sum('quantity');
```

i hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Laravel have very detailed documentation. You just have to browse the documentation site: https://laravel.com/docs.

Your question can be solved using these docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent
- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries